# Test function type with Jest in Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I would like to test an object with contains different functions with Jest. However, I don't want just to verify that properties are functions, but, that they have the right type too. Is it possible with Jest?
Currently, I test:

```
expect(obj).toEqual(
            expect.objectContaining({
                objFunc: expect.any(Function),
            }),
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they have the right type too"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean "right type"? You're asserting on runtime values, the types have already been erased. Have you considered testing that those functions _do the right thing_?

Comment: If the object is an instance of a class you can use [`toBeInstanceOf`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobeinstanceofclass) so you won't have to check the types.

Comment: By right type I mean, for example, that a function gets two strings and returns a string. (a: string,b: string) => string

Comment: If the types of the functions weren't correct, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: You can write [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to assert more complicated types. This kind of function will fail the test if the tested value is of invalid shape.